# would the Solar Gravitational Lens Mission be looking at a specific exoplanet?

Tags: exoplanet, artificial-satellite, nasa

Quoting https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/spacetech/niac/2020_Phase_I_Phase_II/Direct_Multipixel_Imaging_and_Spectroscopy_of_an_Exoplanet/, the proposed Solar Gravitational Lens Mission would "*directly image a habitable Earth-like exoplanet within our stellar neighborhood*".

My question is...  what exoplanet would it be imaging? wikipedia has a whole list of exoplanets that have been found:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_exoplanets

Is it in that list?

Comment: Note that NIAC studies are often for far-future possible technologies that are not ready to be developed into a mission and need a small amount of money to mature the concepts and advance the Technology Readiness Level so they might be used for missions in the future. The awards are for a much smaller amount of money and time than is needed for a full mission concept study and so this particular one, even as a Phase 3 proposal, could still be decades away (or never) from an actual mission

Comment: Also semi-obligatory for any discussion of Technology Readiness Levels: [TRLs with unicorns](https://www.granttremblay.com/blog/trls)

Comment: Should be noted than even if we have a mature technology for sending a spacecraft so far (hundreds of a.u.) - it still should win against concurring missions on "cost vs benefits" basis. Is it better to resolve details of a single planet by the gravitational lens, or to characterise hundreds and thousands of unresolved planets by a set of telescopes, for the same budget?